# Correct Proptype for a regex?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

If I'm passing a regex as a prop (eg: `typeRegex={/Photographer/gi}`), what would be the appropriate PropType?

Answer (score 5):

`PropTypes.instanceOf(RegExp)` Will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 PropTypes.shape(RegExp)
```

Comment: The usage of `Shape` is incorrect